# Define a relative path to `.h` file (C++/ Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

There is a `.h` file need to be accessed by 2 Arduino files (aka "sketches").

Using a relative path is needed since code is compiled using 2 platform, Linux and Mac, so path can not be the same.

```
 |-DIR_A
 |     |-DIR_B (incl. Sketch1)
 |     |
 |     |-DIR_C (incl. Sketch2)
 |     |
 |     |-libfile.h
```

Inside one of the sketches I entered:

`#include "../SerialProtocol.h"`, but compilation failed :

`compilation terminated. exit status 1 ../SerialProtocol.h: No such file or directory`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In C++, `#include` paths are *not* relative to the current source file.  Rather, they are relative to whatever include paths the compiler is configured to use.  This is likely going to be something like `/usr/include`, `/usr/local/include`, and any additional `-I` and `-isystem` flags that your build system adds.

Comment: So the file is named libfile.h (as on the picture) or SerialProtocol.h (as in the text)?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Actual name is ‘SerialProtocol.h’

Comment: @Guy.D, the user "0x5453" is not right here, since relative path are quite common in C++. He mixes system include path (<>) and application include path (""). So, your code should work. Can you pack and share the minimum (non)working example of the problem so that I could take a look? You may send to my email which consist of my name and second name separated by period at google.com.
But make sure that your C++ file is in DIR_B or DIR_C folder first. Maybe it is in DIR_B/DIR_B2 or something like that.

Comment: The `#include` file topic is so well-documented it's hard to understand a question about it these days.

Comment: in `libraries` folder in sketchbook folder create a folder `mylib` and put the h file there. it is **your** `libraries` folder

Comment: @Juraj - I want to have all code confined in `DIR_A` as I called it, and not to scatter it to other directories. TNX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino build system copies all your files into a temporary directory, so you end up with something like this:

```
- TEMP
  - dir_b.tmp123 (contains dir_b sketch files)
  - dir_c.tmp456 (contains dir_c sketch files)
```

libfile.h never gets copied!

Now that you know the problem it's easy to work around it. Here are two suggestions...

### SUGGESTION 1

If you are on Linux and Mac, but not Windows, then you can solve this by using a symlink:

```
|-DIR_A
|     |-DIR_B (incl. Sketch1)
|     |  |-src
|     |  |   |-shared_src (linked)
|     |
|     |-DIR_C (incl. Sketch2)
|     |  |-src
|     |  |   |-shared_src (linked)
|     |
|     |-shared_src
```

create the links using

```
cd dir_b
mkdir src && cd src
ln -s ../../shared_src shared_src

cd ../../dir_c
mkdir src && cd src
ln -s ../../shared_src shared_src
```

I suggest you use the `src` folder, because in there you can also place `.c` and `.cpp` and Arduino will compile them along with your project. Now include the your libraries using:

```
#include "src/shared_src/SerialProtocol.h"
```

### SUGGESTION 2

Do it the oldschool C-Way :D

If you don't need to work on both sketches at the same time, then you can make it a single big sketch, i'll call it `good_program` made of two programs: `sender` and `receiver`

### good_program/good_program.ino

```
#define PROG_SENDER 1
#define PROG_RECEIVER 2

#define PROG PROG_SENDER
```

### good_program/prog_sender.ino

```
#if PROG == PROG_SENDER

void setup(){...}
void update(){...}

#endif
```

### good_program/prog_receiver.ino

```
#if PROG == PROG_RECEIVER

void setup(){...}
void update(){...}

#endif
```

Comment: Suggestion 2 will not work since one is for Arduino AVR board, and the other is for ESP8266

Comment: i see. well, maybe it's too big of a change, but you can always look into platform.io -- it works pretty much like arduino, and gives you a lot more freedom.

Comment: Can it also OTA ?

Answer (score 1):

Arduino builder expects libraries in `libraries` folder in sketchbook folder. Normal would be to create a folder `mylib` there and put the h (and cpp if needed) file there. Even if Arduino IDE Library Manager installs the libraries there it is still your `libraries` folder and you should put your code shared between sketches there.

I understand that you have a project with two sketches for two MCU which communicate and the header file contains shared defines and constants.

In a similar case I have a folder structure like this

```
|-DIR_A
|     |-DIR_B (incl. Sketch1)
|     |  |-sketch 1 files
|     |
|     |-DIR_C (incl. Sketch2)
|     |  |-sketch 2 files
|     |
|     |-LIB_DIR
|     |  |-shared_src
```

and I make a file system link of folder LIB_DIR into the `libraries` folder. It works on Windows and on Linux.

This way you can include the shared headers without path.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly- put `LIB_DIR` inside Arduino's `libraries` folder ?

Comment: no. the folder is in the project folder. the libraries folder has a symlink to it